# How to find the multicast address on Windows

Tags: java, multicast

I'm afraid this is going to be a ridiculously stupid question, you might be able to tell networking is not my strong point, but how can I find the multicast address I am currently connected to?

I was given an application that listens to a multicast address which works fine on one computer, but throws SocketExceptions on another.

I apologise for the vagueness and stupidity of this question but any advice is greatly appreciated. :)

M

Comment: Can you please post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I remember correctly it's something like

```
netsh interface ip show joins
```

in the DOS prompt to see what multicast groups are being listened to.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. If you ever come to Bristol give me a shout and I'll buy you a pint.